# Linux Device Tree for 2 i2c devices on same bus

Tags: linux-device-driver, gpio, i2c, microchip, device-tree

I have 2 port expanders connected to the the I2C of my chip. I am able to configure one port expander from NXP and is able to toggle the gpios. But the second one is from microchip and it is not showing gpios listed as in the previous case. Please let me know how to configure this correctly.

```dts
&i2c1 {
 #address-cells = <1>;
 #size-cells = <0>;
 clock-frequency = <100000>;
 pinctrl-names = "default", "gpio";
 pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c1>;
 scl-gpios = <&lsio_gpio0 xx GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
 sda-gpios = <&lsio_gpio0 xx GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
 status = "okay";

mcp23017: gpio@10 {
 compatible = "microchip,mcp23017";
 reg = <0x10>;
 gpio-controller;
 #gpio-cells = <2>;
};

pca6416: gpio@11 {
 compatible = "ti,tca6416";
 reg = <0x11>;
 gpio-controller;
 #gpio-cells = <2>;
};
```

Comment: Microchip one is a pin control, and not old simple GPIO chip, you have to use pinctrl bindings.

Comment: According to the MCP23017 datasheet, the I2C address set by its A2, A1 and A0 pins will be in the range 0x20 to 0x27, but you have it set to 0x10 in your device tree node.